# Convert generic list to java object

Tags: java, arrays, list, object

I am performing a query on a database and I get in return a generic List of objects. The overall object is structured as followed:

```
List<E> objDetails =
    [0] --> ["name1", "value1"]
    [1] --> ["name2", "value2"]
    ....
    [n] --> ["nameN", "valueN"]
```

In short, I get back an array of objects, and in each element, there are name and values pairs that I want access to. What is the easiest way to get to these values? I am thinking of casting this whole list into a perhaps self-designed class that can hold names/values. The catch is that one is a string and the other is an integer.

What are my options?

EDIT:

Here are two classes I tried defining in order to solve this problem

```
private static class Clinic {

    public List<ClinicDetails> details;
}

private static class ClinicDetails {

    private Integer objectID;
    private String healthName;

}

List<Clinic> clinic = DataServices.getResult(q);
```

EDIT 2:

Here is how I solved this problem

```
        List<Object[]> clinic = DataServices.getResult(q);

        for(Object[] obj: clinic) {

            for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(obj[i]);
                // will store in my own list now that I can access it
            }
        }
```

Comment: "_self-designed class that can hold names/values_"... do you really want to reinvent the wheel? Why not using a map?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I agree! Can you show me briefly how to do that?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza because they're less efficient, take more memory, are less type-safe, require casts if several types of values are stored in it, don't allow for code-completion and refactoring?

Comment: Yes, you should create a class containing two properties names and value, of type String and int (or Integer) respectively.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you quickly show me how to do that? I tried doing this with a class I made but the values didn't end of getting mapped to it.

Comment: How about you showing us what you tried instead? Things won't happen magically. You need to loop through the arrays, and transform each of them into an instance of your class.

Comment: You get a `List<Object[]>`. The `Object[]` objects contain your key, value pairs.

Comment: @JBNizet See my edits, sorry I didn't post with this before. I'll try what you said though

Comment: @JBNizet If OP is using Hibernate, then perhaps Result Transformers will come handy :)

Comment: Read my previous comment. Your query returns a List<Object[]>, i.e. a list containing elements of type Object[], where each element is thus an array containing two values. Pretending this list is a List<Clinic> won't magically transform these arrays into instances of Clinics. By doing that, you're just lying to yourself, and will get runtime exceptions. And BTW, this return type doesn't even make sense. You want a List<ClinicDetails>, not a List<Clinic>. But to have that, you need to loop through the arrays and transform each f them into an instance of ClinicDetails.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the help JB, I'm usually better with this stuff but what was messing me up was my type. Before I had `List<Object>` but `List<Object[]` solved all my problems

Answer (score 1):

A simple map would look like this:

```
Map m=new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("Key", "Value");
m.put("Key2", "Value2");
assertEquals(m.get("Key"), "Value");
assertEquals(m.get("Key2"), "Value2");
```

These solve a lot of use cases but aren't very good for long-term reusable objects.  Everyone uses "Hashes" but if you are good you'll isolate their usage to a single method or a single class.

Comment: Note that the OP must be sure that his ID's are unique in order to make this work.

Comment: From his example that's what it looked like he was going for.

Answer (score 0):

This would implement a generic object that would be reuseable as you've described.

Cheers!

```
`    public interface node<K,N> {
    public K getKey();
    public N getValue();
}
public class LogicalNode<K,N> implements node<K,N>{
    private K key;
    private N value;
    public LogicalNode(K key, N value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public K getKey() {return key;}
    public N getValue() {return value;}
}
public class arr2lst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<node<String, Integer>> rs = new ArrayList<node<String,Integer>>();
        rs.add(new LogicalNode<String, Integer>("name", nbr));
        rs.add(new LogicalNode<String, Integer>("name2", nbr2));
    }
}`
```